# I need help redoing this code but without the use of the built in dot product

Tags: built-in-symbols

```
mat = Table[
   If[i == j, .5, If[i == j - 1 || i == j + 1, .25, 0]], {i, 1, 
50}, {j, 1, 50}];
b = Table[1./i, {i, 1, 50}];
old = Table[1, {i, 1, 50}]; new = Table[1, {i, 1, 50}];
stopthreshold = 10^-5;
dim = 50;
For[i = 1, i <= 1000, i++, n = 1; 
 For[n = 1, n <= dim, n++, 
If[n == 1, new[[n]] = 2*(1 - .25*old[[2]]), 
If[n == dim, new[[n]] = 2*(1/n - .25*old[[dim - 1]]),
        new[[n]] = 2*(1/n - .25*old[[n - 1]] - .25*old[[n + 1]])]
]
];
   error = Sqrt[(old - new)*(old - new)]/Sqrt[new.new];
 If
 [
     error < stopthreshold, Break[]
 ];
  old = new 
]
new;
```

Here is the code. As you can see I used the built in dot product but is there any way in which I could correct this so it does not use that built in function.

Comment: What is the issue with using `Dot`?

Comment: Build the matrix like this: m = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 0.5, Band[{2, 1}] -> 0.25, 
Band[{1, 2}] -> 0.25}, {50, 50}] // Normal. But I don't see where you use Dot in the code you present.

Comment: I was told by my professor I need to do this code but without using the dot product or any form of builtin multiplication!  Which I am guessing is in reference to what is in the If statements

Comment: `new.new` is the same as `Total[new^2]`, which avoids `Dot`. You could also use `Inner` or `TensorContract[new\[TensorProduct]new, {{1, 2}}]`. And `Sqrt[new.new]` is the same as `Norm[new]`.

Comment: Were you told by your professor that *you* are to do it, or that you are to ask somebody else to do it for you?

Comment: I was told to correct it but I was unsure! I did see that method of squaring it but I did not think it would work in terms lets say if I were to apply it to matrix multiplication so I was unsure overall. Although, I do appreciate the assistance